# How do I approach Laravel Eloquent Relationships when there is a joint table involved?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

For context - I have 2 models/tables and 1 joint table between them. They are:

1. Category (Model/Table/Controller)
2. Course (Model/Table/Controller)
3. CategoryCourse (Model/Table)

As you can see, CategoryCourse is the joint table. In the Category table - I have predefined categories like "Business" or "Web Development" and each Course can have multiple categories.

So for example - a "Laravel" Course has the "Backend" and "Web Development" categories. And this relation is stored in the CategoryCourse table with category_id & course_id.

Now my question is - how do I form eloquent relationships between the 3 models? If I only had 2 models i.e Category & Course - it's a little more obvious. But now - I'm confused because I have 3 models. So what relationship goes into which model? Because I want to be able to print all categories of a course in a table cell. How do I achieve this?

Schema for the 3 tables is:

```
courses: {
  id, name, difficulty, price
}

category: {
  id, name
}

categorycourse {
  id, course_id, category_id
}
```

Kindly chime in and guide me - I'm a little new to Relationships in Laravel and I really want to use to them correctly.

Comment: you dont need 3 models, you only need 2, the pivot is handled for you via the relationship ... that is what the Belongs To Many relationship is for

Comment: Read the documentation for Many-to-many in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. As lagbox said, you don't need a `CategoryCourse` model (although you _can_ use one, but it's benefits are limited: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models). If you have a specific question, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72451309/edit) to include more information.

Answer (score 2):

Both models (`Course` & `Category`) can have a `belongsToMany` relation associated with the other model, which tells laravel that there is a pivot (join table) that connects the two of them. There is no need for the third Model, since the framework deals with the pivot table behind the scenes.

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public function categories(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function courses(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class);
    }
}
```

You can then query `Course::with('categories')->first()->categories` & `Category::with('courses')->first()->courses`.

You can learn more about `Many to Many` relationships in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Providing an example of how to define these relationships would make this answer more helpful.

Comment: Also, you don't need to start queries with `::query()`; `Course::with()-> // ...` will have the same result. I'm seeing this `Model::query()-> // ...` approach more and more these days, and I'm curious why; did you see that in a tutorial or something else?

Comment: @TimLewis used to using `query()` to start queries that don't include `with()` in the chain, since it gives you access to the the `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class and possible methods. In this example they are completelly not needed, since the `with` method returns the same.

Comment: In my 8 years of Laravel experience, the only time I used `::query()` is when I had to add things, like `$query = Model::query(); // a bunch of unrelated code ...; $query = $query->where(...); // etc.` I've always got the expected result without it  `Model::get()` is the same as `Model::query()->get()`, `Model::query()->where(...)->first()` is the same as `Model::where()->first()`, etc etc. Cheers for the rationalization, and good answer overall too!

Comment: @TimLewis its for IDE purposes not actual code reasons

Comment: @lagbox Ah, that makes a lot more sense!